# dplyr::mutate() -- In a tibble nesting lists, how to ignore NULL nested lists?

Tags: r, list, dplyr, null, tibble

Occasionally, nested lists in my higher level `tibble` are `NULL`. I want to ***ignore*** those lists when using `dplyr::mutate()`.

### Example

#### Recoding values to lower case & underscore

**Data**

```r
library(tibble)

df <-
  tibble(movies = c("The Shawshank Redemption", "The Godfather", "The Godfather: Part II", "The Dark Knight", "12 Angry Men"),
                continents = c("Asia", "Australia", "America", "Africa", "Europe"),
                michaels = c("Michael Jackson", "Michael Jordan", "Mike Tyson", "Michael Phelps", "Michael Schumacher"))

df <- add_column(df, ignore_me = list(NULL))

df

## # A tibble: 5 x 4
##   movies                   continents michaels           ignore_me
##   <chr>                    <chr>      <chr>              <list>   
## 1 The Shawshank Redemption Asia       Michael Jackson    <NULL>   
## 2 The Godfather            Australia  Michael Jordan     <NULL>   
## 3 The Godfather: Part II   America    Mike Tyson         <NULL>   
## 4 The Dark Knight          Africa     Michael Phelps     <NULL>   
## 5 12 Angry Men             Europe     Michael Schumacher <NULL>
```

**Trying to recode values**

```r
library(dplyr) # version 1.0.2
library(snakecase)

df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), snakecase::to_any_case))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`. 
> x argument is not a character vector 
> i Input `..1` is `across(everything(), snakecase::to_any_case)`.

---

Obviously, either of the following would work:

```r
df %>% mutate(across(c(movies, continents, michaels), snakecase::to_any_case))
# or
df %>% mutate(across(-ignore_me, snakecase::to_any_case))

##   movies                   continents michaels           ignore_me
##   <chr>                    <chr>      <chr>              <list>   
## 1 the_shawshank_redemption asia       michael_jackson    <NULL>   
## 2 the_godfather            australia  michael_jordan     <NULL>   
## 3 the_godfather_part_ii    america    mike_tyson         <NULL>   
## 4 the_dark_knight          africa     michael_phelps     <NULL>   
## 5 12_angry_men             europe     michael_schumacher <NULL>
```

**But in reality I can't expect which column/nested list is going to be `NULL`** and therefore I need my code to simply ignore such `NULL` but still apply on non-NULL columns.

---

#### EDIT

---

Original `df` above makes it simple to solve the problem by ignoring `list` altogether. But data can typically also be:

```r
df_2 <-
  tibble(movies = c("The Shawshank Redemption", "The Godfather", "The Godfather: Part II", "The Dark Knight", "12 Angry Men"),
         continents = c("Asia", "Australia", "America", "Africa", "Europe"),
         michaels = c("Michael Jackson", "Michael Jordan", "Mike Tyson", "Michael Phelps", "Michael Schumacher"))

df_2 <- add_column(df_2, ignore_me = list(NULL))

set.seed(2021) ; df_2 <- mutate(df_2, across(sample(colnames(df_2), 1), as.list))

df_2

##   movies                   continents michaels  ignore_me
##   <chr>                    <chr>      <list>    <list>   
## 1 The Shawshank Redemption Asia       <chr [1]> <NULL>   
## 2 The Godfather            Australia  <chr [1]> <NULL>   
## 3 The Godfather: Part II   America    <chr [1]> <NULL>   
## 4 The Dark Knight          Africa     <chr [1]> <NULL>   
## 5 12 Angry Men             Europe     <chr [1]> <NULL>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore all the list columns :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(where(Negate(is.list)), snakecase::to_any_case))
```

Or if not all `list` column are going to be `NULL`, you can specifically find the columns that have `NULL` value by checking their length and ignore the columns that have length as 0.

```
df %>% mutate(across(where(~!all(lengths(.) == 0)), snakecase::to_any_case))


#  movies                   continents michaels           ignore_me
#  <chr>                    <chr>      <chr>              <list>   
#1 the_shawshank_redemption asia       michael_jackson    <NULL>   
#2 the_godfather            australia  michael_jordan     <NULL>   
#3 the_godfather_part_ii    america    mike_tyson         <NULL>   
#4 the_dark_knight          africa     michael_phelps     <NULL>   
#5 12_angry_men             europe     michael_schumacher <NULL>
```

For modified `df_2` we could use :

```
df_2$michaels[[3]] <- c(df_2$michaels[[3]], df_2$michaels[[4]]) 

df_2 %>% 
  mutate(across(where(~all(lengths(.) > 0)), 
                ~relist(to_any_case(unlist(.)), .)))


#  movies                   continents michaels  ignore_me
#  <chr>                    <chr>      <list>    <list>   
#1 the_shawshank_redemption asia       <chr [1]> <NULL>   
#2 the_godfather            australia  <chr [1]> <NULL>   
#3 the_godfather_part_ii    america    <chr [2]> <NULL>   
#4 the_dark_knight          africa     <chr [1]> <NULL>   
#5 12_angry_men             europe     <chr [1]> <NULL>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option with the addition of `purrr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(across(where(~ !all(map_lgl(., is.null))), to_any_case))

  movies                   continents michaels           ignore_me
  <chr>                    <chr>      <chr>              <list>   
1 the_shawshank_redemption asia       michael_jackson    <NULL>   
2 the_godfather            australia  michael_jordan     <NULL>   
3 the_godfather_part_ii    america    mike_tyson         <NULL>   
4 the_dark_knight          africa     michael_phelps     <NULL>   
5 12_angry_men             europe     michael_schumacher <NULL>
```

For the second dataset:

```
df_2 %>%
 mutate(across(where(~ !all(map_lgl(., is.null))), ~ to_any_case(unlist(.)))) 

  movies                   continents michaels           ignore_me
  <chr>                    <chr>      <chr>              <list>   
1 the_shawshank_redemption asia       michael_jackson    <NULL>   
2 the_godfather            australia  michael_jordan     <NULL>   
3 the_godfather_part_ii    america    mike_tyson         <NULL>   
4 the_dark_knight          africa     michael_phelps     <NULL>   
5 12_angry_men             europe     michael_schumacher <NULL>
```